# Laravel withCount() returns null

Tags: php, laravel

I need to count the results of Many-to-Many relation subquery.

```
return $q->withCount(['users' => function($q) {
    $q->select("Users.Id as Id_user","Users.Name");
}])->get()
```

This code doesn't work. It return null.

However, that works fine and successfully adds users_count column:

```
return $q->withCount(['users'])->get();
```

But I need to make select subquery to select specific columns from the relation so I need my first variant get to work.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It looks like you the query result would not return any fields in the `users` table in the first place. i.e it returns `users_count` only. Isn't this the normal behaviour of `withCount()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you use `Count` or `withCount` method, the query builder does a `select count(id) as aggregate`

if in the condition par of the `withCount` you override the `select` part. it breaks

```
return $q->withCount(['users' => function($q) {
    //here you are supposed to do condition, not a select
    $q->select("Users.Id as Id_user","Users.Name");
}])->get()
```

if you want the id and the name of the user, use `with`

```
return $q->withCount(['users'])
    ->with(['users' => function($q) {
        $q->select("Users.Id as Id_user","Users.Name");
    }])
    ->get()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That helped!

Answer (score 1):

You can make getAttribute for users_count and overwrite the results to be 0 instead to null

just go to the model that has the relation users and create "getUsersCountAttribute" function like this:

```
public function getUsersCountAttribute($value)
{
    return (int) !empty($value) ? $value : 0;
}
```

Or in php 7.x and later:

```
public function getUsersCountAttribute($value)
{
    return (int) $value ?? 0;
}
```

Try now your code. You will find the value will be 0 in case null

```
return $q->withCount('users')->get();
```